# How to set a collection name in MongoDB

Tags: python, discord.py, pymongo

I encountered such a problem, I do not know how to set the name of this collection through the code when creating a collection, that is, I write:

```
cluster = MongoClient("link")
db = cluster.BananiData
collection = db.ctx.guild.id
```

but the name is set as ctx.guild.id, I need to insert the server ID in the name, how can this be implemented?

P.S: I use python

code:

```
cluster = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://Bananchik:hdkkIFkk6VKywSDH@cluster0.olcto.mongodb.net/<BananiData>?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
db = cluster.BananiData
collection = db.ctx.guild.id
#collection = cluster.BananiData.LevelSystem

class DataBases(commands.Cog):
    """ ФСБ? """
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    @commands.check(permissions.is_owner)
    async def test_db(self, ctx):
        
        await ctx.send(collection)

        await ctx.send("DB id created")

        for member in ctx.guild.members:
            print(member)
            post = {
                "_id": member.id,
                "xp": 0,
                "lvl": 1,
                "message_count": 0

            }

            if collection.count_documents({"_id": member.id}) == 0:
                collection.insert_one(post)
                print(f"Пользователь **{member.name}** добавлен в базу данных")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to enclose the name you want to assign to a collection inside a
square bracket if you are using python.

Example:

If you want to create a collection by the name "SampleCollection", you could use the below command, even though
`.` operator works.

```
collection = db["SampleCollection"]
```

Therefore,

You should change the collection initialization code like the following:

```
collection = db[ctx.guild.id]
```

> Note: Make sure that `ctx.guild.id` variable is of type `str` else it won't work.